# How can I automate the hiding of PowerPoint slides?

Tags: vba, office365, powerpoint

I use PowerPoint in my lectures and print a subset of the slides for my students (to allow them to fill in blanks before I show my answers). Currently, I put a light blue circle at the bottom left of slides that I want to hide while printing (but not while lecturing). I then manually hide slides when it is time to print them, then unhide all of the slides before lecturing. Is there any way to automate this process? I use Office 365 on both PCs and Macs.

Comment: You can have a macro for xustom print: hide all the slides that has this unique light blue circle shape (outside of the slide?) before print, then unhide them after printed.

Comment: @PatricK Thank you. How would I tell programmatically if a slide has that shape? (It's actually on screen, which is fine with me.)

Comment: One way see what the shape is named: click `Home`, `Select` (in Editing group), `Selection pane...`. if you have the same shapes on other Non-Answers page, you should add text inside to distinguish it. In the long run, you should develope custom macro to "Stamp" and "UnStamp" this Answer Page Circle, along with "Print Student Handouts".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started, save this as pptm then save a copy as addin:

**`ChangeAnswersSlideState`** - changes activeslide to be an Answer Slide or not
**`PrintStudentHandout`** - Hide Answer slides and then print, then unhide

```
Option Explicit

Private Const ANS_ID As String = "ANS"

Sub PrintStudentHandout()
    ChangeAnswersSlideVisible
    With ActivePresentation
        .PrintOptions.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
        .PrintOut
    End With
    ChangeAnswersSlideVisible msoFalse
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeAnswersSlideVisible(Optional Hide As MsoTriState = msoTrue)
    Dim oSlide As Slide, oShp As Shape
    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oShp In oSlide.Shapes
            If IsAnswersShape(oShp) Then
                oSlide.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = Hide
                Exit For
            End If
        Next oShp
    Next oSlide
End Sub

Sub ChangeAnswersSlideState()
    Dim oShp As Shape, bChanged As Boolean
    bChanged = False
    For Each oShp In Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes
        If IsAnswersShape(oShp) Then
            oShp.Delete
            bChanged = True
        End If
    Next oShp
    If Not bChanged Then MakeAnswersSlide
End Sub

Private Sub MakeAnswersSlide(Optional ByRef AnswerSlide As Slide = Nothing)
    If AnswerSlide Is Nothing Then Set AnswerSlide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
    With AnswerSlide.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, -80, 460, 72, 72)
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ANS_ID
    End With
End Sub

Private Function IsAnswersShape(ByRef CheckShape As Shape) As Boolean
    Dim bIsAnAnswerShape As Boolean
    bIsAnAnswerShape = False
    With CheckShape
        If .AutoShapeType = msoShapeOval Then
            If .HasTextFrame Then
                If .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ANS_ID Then
                    bIsAnAnswerShape = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
    IsAnswersShape = bIsAnAnswerShape
End Function
```

Comment: Super! That works. I have the macro working. Next step is to convert it to an add-in. I'll be back. I'm deleting my prior comments.

Comment: You can customise the Home Ribbon with this guide [Custom UI Editor For Microsoft Office](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm) to call these Subs, builtin icons can be looked at [here](http://soltechs.net/CustomUI/imageMso01.asp). Enjoy!

Comment: Alas, the Custom UI Editor didn't work for me. When I tried installing it, I was told I needed to install .NET 3.0. I believe I do have it installed (among more recent versions).

Comment: After a day or two of messing around with Visual Studio, I found that I could add the buttons through PowerPoint: File > Options > Customize Ribbon. Thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer is a bit over complicated imo. Ultimately, for a given slide object `oSlide`:

```
'To hide a slide
oSlide.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = True

'To show a slide
oSlide.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = false
```